# How can I use right curly braces in MathTımeProfessional II?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mtpro

I want to wrap 2 or more cases in right *curly* brace using the MathTıme Professional II font. When I use 2 lines it seems to work, but with 3 or more it doesn't show correctly.
I've used this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
  \begin{document}

  $\left.
    \begin{aligned}
      &\frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{16}}=\frac{3}{4}=0,75\;\\ % use \quad as spacer between  equation and right brace
      &\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}}=\sqrt{0,5625}=0,75
      \end{aligned}
      \right\}\Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{16}}=\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}}$
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Shows correctly for me. What problem do you see? Maybe you could add a picture.

Comment: It shows the normal brace of the amsmath package.

Comment: Note: write `0{,}5625` instead of `0,5625` in order to get the correct spacing.

Comment: You re right. I use a special package for the comma decimal mark but i think this way is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, see Section 2.12.2 of the documentation. If You want a curly brace here, use the `\LEFTRIGHT.\}{...}` construct. The period is the empty left delimiter here.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[%
  \LEFTRIGHT.\}{%
    \begin{aligned}
      &\frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{16}}=\frac{3}{4}=0,75\;\\ % use \quad as spacer between equation and right brace
      &\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}}=\sqrt{0,5625}=0,75
      \end{aligned}
    }%
    \Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{16}}=\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: There are predefined ones as `\PAREN{…}`. By the way, may be it would be good to add the `\SQRT{…}` construction, which gives you the slanted `\sqrt` sign for bigger sizes.

Comment: @Manuel `\PARENS{...}` gives (round) parentheses, I don't see where this should be used here. Regarding the roots: the OP didn't asked for different roots, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Just to add some info about special commands from the `mtpro2` package. But if you think that you shouldn't add that info, ok, I just pointed it.